# how to make a copy by values for a JSON?

Tags: python, json, list, copy

I need to append the data JSON into a list of data in the bigger JSON, but I get a copy by references, but i need a copy by values, here is my code:

```
dataJS = {}
dataJS['data'] = []
data = {}
for d in res:
    data['ver'] = d[0]
    data['exp'] = "{\"DT\": \"1344\", \"Vl\": 757}"

    print("data : ", data )

    dataJS['data'].append(data)

print("\n\n")
for i in dataJS['data']:
    print("JsData : ", i)
print("\n\n")
```

And my result is :

```
data :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 1}
data :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 5}
data :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 6}
data :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 9}
data :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}



JsData :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}
JsData :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}
JsData :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}
JsData :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}
JsData :  {'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}', 'ver': 12}
```

Any help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create one single `data` dict before the loop, and keep on overwriting it's values and appending it to your list. The key point here is that it the *same single dict* that gets appended to your list - in Python, **assignment never creates a new copy** of your object (whatever type it is). [There's a very good article about this here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and I strongly suggest you spend a couple minutes reading it (and experimenting along in a python shell) so you understand how python's "variables" differ from the most common C-style ones.

In your case, the solution is obvious: create a new `data` dict at each iteration, ie:

```
dataJS = {'data': []}
for d in res:
    data = {
        'ver': d[0], 
        'exp': '{"DT": "1344", "Vl": 757}'
        }
    dataJS["data"].append(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer :

with the function : 
`data.copy()` that copy the values,

```
dataJS[pat] = {}
dataJS[pat]['version'] = newVersion
dataJS[pat]['data'] = []

data = {}
for i, d in enumerate(res) :
    data['type'] = d[2]
    data['exp'] = d[3]
    data['val'] = d[4]
    print("\n\n")
    print("d[4]",d[4])
    print("\n\n")
    dataJS[pat]['data'].append(data.copy())
```

so `dataJS['data'].append(data.copy())` works fine.

Comment: Creating the `data` dict directly within the loop would be even simpler...

Answer (score 0):

Python makes shallow copies to objects by default. There is a library which can help you called `copy`. The command you are going to need to invoke is `copy.deepcopy(myVar)` which will make a copy of the contents a.k.a **deep copy**(as you guessed)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Python doesn't "make shallow copies" on assignment, it makes no copy at all unless specifically asked for.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be reducing scope of `data` -

```
dataJS['data'] = []
for d in res:
    data = {}
    data['ver'] = d[0]
    ...
```

Comment: bruno's answer provides an in-depth explanation.